# Minimal 'touching' subgraph

Tags: graph-theory

Whilst playing [Rimworld](https://rimworldgame.com/) it dawned to me that a part of the game (at least how I play it) was finding an optimal solution to the following problem:

Given a finite connected graph $V$ (just denoting the set of vertices), find a subset $W \subset V$ such that

- $W$ is connected
- Every point of $V \setminus W$ is adjacent to some point of $W$
- $\lvert W \rvert$ is minimal with respect to the above two requirements

This sounds like it could be a well-studied problem, but I know very little about graph theory and would not know where to look. If it is too hard to approach in general, one could first limit to the case where $W$ is an $n \times m$ grid, with two vertices being adjacent if they lie next to each other vertically or horizontally. From playing with it, I would suspect some cauliflower-like shape appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, in general this is the connected dominating set problem ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_dominating_set)), for which no efficient algorithm is known.

As the Wikipedia link mentions, this is related to finding a spanning tree with the maximum number of leaves. More precisely, given a connected dominating set $W$, construct a spanning tree $T$ for the graph by first taking a spanning tree for $W$, and then joining every vertex $V \setminus W$ to one of its neighbors in $W$.

Every vertex in $V \setminus W$ is a leaf, and no vertex of $W$ should be a leaf in an optimal solution: that means it's not used to connect to any vertex of $V \setminus W$, so we should remove it. So if we want to minimize $|W|$, we want to maximize the number of leaves in $T$.

For grid graphs, we can get an approximately-optimal solution very easily. In an $m \times n$ grid graph, there are $mn$ vertices. If $k$ of them are leaves and $mn-k$ are non-leaves, then the non-leaf vertices can have degree at most $4$, so the sum of the degrees is at most $k + 4(mn-k) = 4mn - 3k$. But the sum of the degrees is twice the number of edges, which must be $2mn-2$. So $$2mn -2  \le 4mn - 3k \implies 3k \le 2mn + 2 \implies k \le \frac23mn + \frac23.$$ Since $W$ consists of the nonleaf vertices, $|W| \ge mn - k \ge \frac13 mn - \frac23$: we must include at least $\frac13$ of the vertices in $W$.

Here's a construction that achieves $|W| < \frac13mn + m + n$:

[image: example for 7 by 12 grid]